# magento 2 tables not created in the database using installerschema

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.7

The module is correctly enabled and it shows in the setup_module - and i can see him on front end with the route. But tables is not created in the database. I don't no whats wrong in it.

My installerschema.php:

```
<?php
namespace Inchoo\Helloworld\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface {

    public function install( SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        /**
         * Create table 'posts'
         */
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable( 'inchoo_blog_posts' )
        )->addColumn(
            'post_id',
            Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            [ 'identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true ],
            'Post ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'title',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [ 'nullable' => false ],
            'Post Title'
        )->addColumn(
            'content',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            '2M',
            [ ],
            'Post Content'
        )->setComment(
            'Blog Post Table'
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->createTable( $table );

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Try deleting from the table setup_module the record with module = 'Inchoo_Helloworld';

Answer (score 3):

compare your installschema: (you missed to inject   \Framework\DB\Ddl\Table)

```
     use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
     use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
     use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
     use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

   class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
 {
/**
 * Installs DB schema for a module
 *
 * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 */
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    if (!$installer->tableExists('table_name')) {
        $table = $installer->getConnection()
            ->newTable($installer->getTable('table_name'))
            ->addColumn(
                'id',
                Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                10,
                ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true, 'unsigned' => true]
            )->addColumn(
                'store_id',
                 Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                 10, 
                 ['nullable' => false]
            )->addColumn(
                'title',
                 Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                 '2M', 
                 ['nullable' => false]
            )->addColumn(
                'description',
                 Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                 '2M', 
                 ['default' => ''], 
                 'Description'
            )->addColumn(
                'creation_time',
                 Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
                 null, 
                 ['nullable' => false], 'Creation Time'
            )->addColumn(
                'update_time', 
                Table::TYPE_DATETIME, 
                null, 
                ['nullable' => false], 
                'Update Time'
            )->setComment('table comments');        
     }

    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

}